# What's the best way to include PHP code in pages?

Tags: php, pages, include

I'm currently creating a bunch of (empty) pages and performing conditionals such as `is_page('Blabla')` on it, which increases my page.php significantly. I'm already using `require_once` for different content, but is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has a function for including template parts, which you can use for that purpose : [get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

You can also use `include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/myfunction.php');`

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/412301/45516

But I will summarize my answer here also.

There are three ways to include a file.

1. Enforce use of parent theme's directory:

```php
require get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

2. Permit use of parent theme of child theme's directory if there is one:

```php
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

3. Use within a plugin:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

The `plugin_dir_path()` offer no specific benefit over these methods.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/ for more details.

Avoid `include`, use `require` because a missing file won't stay unnoticed.