# The proper way to include/require PHP files in WordPress

Tags: theme-development, themes, include

I'm a new WordPress developer and recently I've been having problems (on multiple sites) with `include_once` and `require_once` for PHP files. If I include `(get_theme_directory_uri() . 'subdir/file')` the specified file gets included (or required, which leads to fatal errors) but if any WordPress functions are called within 'file' I get something similar to:

> '**Call to undefined function** `add_action()` in /full/path/to/file'.

The apparent solution I've found is to do:

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/subdir/filename");
```

Is this right or did I miss 'the WordPress way' to include files somewhere?

Comment: Please have look at links, might be helpful http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/111628/include-a-external-php-file-into-a-wordpress-custom-template

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7398/how-to-include-php-files-in-plugins-the-correct-way

Answer (score 25):

If you check https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri

You will see `get_template_directory_uri()` returns a uri, not a server path.

You should use instead the `get_template_directory()` function, which returns the path to the theme, without trailing slash:

```
include get_template_directory() . '/subdir/filename.php';
```

For a plugin you can use the `plugin_dir_path()` function:

```
include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/subdir/filename.php';
```

Comment: I want to note that this is mostly intended for locating paths in _arbitrary_ plugin. Within inside of _specific_ plugin the relative paths are known and basic PHP includes (sans any WP bits) are a normal practice.

Comment: With Rarst comment i realized my anwser is for plugins, not themes. For themes, use get_template_directory() instead of get_template_directory_uri(). Easy!

Comment: you might want to try - /subdir/filename.php?

Comment: @Jon thanks, same observation. Submitted an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 19):

WordPress 4.7+ introduce get_theme_file_path() functions to include file on WordPress theme.

Include like this:

```
include get_theme_file_path( '/subdir/filename.php' );
```

The advantage of using this function is on child theme you can override the parent theme file.

Reference : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_path/

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! This should be the correct answer now.

Comment: Exactly, WP updated the helper to do so, this is the good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the following examples, I assume you are using composer and a child theme might be enabled or not.

1. Use this method if you want to include a file within a theme and want to ensure the parent theme's directory is used even if a child theme is enabled:

```php
require get_template_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

2. Or use this method if you want to include a file within a theme and don't mind whether the parent theme's directory is used or the child theme's directory is used if a child theme is enabled:

```php
require get_stylesheet_directory() . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

3. And lastly, use this method if you want to include a file within a plugin:

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

Be careful with the last method because the magic constant `__DIR__` will have a different value depending on the directory in which your php file is located.

Note that there's no benefit to using the `plugin_dir_path()` function as it is just a wrapper to the `trailingslashit()` function.

The documentation says:

> The “plugin” part of the name is misleading – it can be used for any file, and will not return the directory of a plugin unless you call it within a file in the plugin’s base directory.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/ for more details.

Also note that using `include` is poor practice because a missing file will only raise a warning. Always use `require` instead, because a missing file will raise a fatal error and won't stay unnoticed.